# 2 buttons activating form submission

Tags: html, forms, bootstrap-4

I have 2 buttons in my form 1 for submittiong and 1 for going to the previous page but both do the same thing.
how does this happen?

```
            <div style="position:fixed; left: 50px; top:13%; z-index: 100;">
                <a href="index.php<?=$link?>"><button class="btn btn-warning">Terug</button></a>
                <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success">Volgende</button>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Html Buttons there are several types

`type='button', type='reset', type='submit'`

Okay What Do These Do ?

With `type='button'`, you just mean it's a normal button which doesn't do anything

With `type='submit'`, you mean it's a button which submits a form

With `type='reset'`, you mean it's a button which resets the values of a form's fields.

With no type, it defaults to `type='submit'` automatically.

```
<div style="position:fixed; left: 50px; top:13%; z-index: 100;">
                <a href="index.php<?=$link?>"><button class="btn btn-warning">Terug</button></a>
                <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success">Volgende</button>
            </div>
```

You could just add `type='button'` to the button you want to be normal or

You could add a little javascript to make it not behave like a submit button.

`<button class="btn btn-warning" onclick='event.preventDefault()'>Terug</button>`

Answer (score 1):

Made a fix that works but still don't know why:
I changed the first `<button>` to `<div>` and now they do work as intended:

```
<a href="index.php<?=$link?>"><div class="btn btn-warning">Terug</div></a>
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success">Volgende</button>
```

Comment: it works since you removed the button. You have to put the type="button" to the cancel button if you want. Or you can handle some js for button click instead